# ¿Como obtener los fines de semana(sabado y domingo) de un dataframe con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un dataframe que tiene mediciones en diferentes horas del dia durante varios años, encontré la media de estas mediciones de lunes a viernes utilizando .resample("B").mean(), pero ahora no se como obtener el de los fines de semana, agradecería mucho una respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", freq="D"))
df['column'] = np.random.randn(len(df)

# Suponiendo que tus fechas están en el índice como en el ejemplo que pongo
df.loc[df.index.weekday >= 5, :].resample("W").mean()
```

En la última línea lo que haces es seleccionar los días del fin de semana (lunes es 0 y domingo es 6 por lo que 5 y 6 son el fin de semana). Luego haces el `resample` de la semana (solo habrá días de fin de semana) y le aplicas la operación que quieras (`mean` según pones en tu pregunta).

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de gran utilidad